# copyValuesToRange changing Date format

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using the .copyValuesToRange function in a Google Script to copy some information from an input page to a historical page in a Google Sheets file.  One of the cells in the range that is being copied is a Date, formatted MM/DD.

I have two of these input pages, and two corresponding historical pages.  When I run the copyToValueRange() on the first input page -> historical page, it copies over all of the values properly.  When I run the script for the second page, it copies the Date in MM/DD format and transforms it into Microsoft timestamp (#####).

At first I thought it was putting a random integer there, but after a bit of searching and the help of a calculator site (http://www.silisoftware.com/tools/date.php), I've found that it's actually converting the Date into a different format.

Why is this happening on one call to copyValuesToRange() and not the other?  Do I need to somehow handle the Date format using Utilities.formatDate()?

Answer (score 2):

The method `copyValuesToRange` does what it promises to do: copies *values* to range. In a Google spreadsheet, the date "4/28/2016" is just the number 42488 that happened to be formatted as a date. So this number gets copied over, as designed.

You want to copy both the values **and** formatting. For this, use the [copyTo](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination) method:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
sheet.getRange("A1:A5").copyTo(sheet.getRange("B1:B5"));
```

---

The method `copyValuesToRange` looks pretty old to me (it takes "gridId" parameter that almost no other method uses). I consider it obsolete now that `copyTo` is available. The method `copyTo` also accepts options indicating whether to copy only contents, only formatting, or both (default).

---

And no, you don't want `Utilities.formatDate`. This method is often mistaken for a device to format spreadsheet cells. That's not what it does; it converts dates to strings.